# If statement on UIButton selection

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

Im not sure why this is not working:

```
- (IBAction)sliderValueChanged:(UISlider *)sender {
    if (_menuRightItem2.selected == YES) {
        NSLog(@"yes");
        if (sender == self.slider1)
            [sender setValue:((int)((slider1.value + 1) / 1.0) - 1.0) animated:NO];
        else if (sender == self.slider2)
            [sender setValue:((int)((slider2.value + 1) / 1.0) - 1.0) animated:NO];
    }
    barHeight = slider1.value * -20 + slider2.value * -50; //! hoogte in de min, yea right.
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.50 animations:^{
        self.orangeView.frame = CGRectMake(595, 615, 80, barHeight);
    }];
}
```

What I'm trying to accomplish is that when `menuRightItem2` is selected that it then executes my `if else` statement and otherwise does not. But my `NSLog()` isn't even working. What would be the correct way to achieve this?

**My button statement:**

```
- (IBAction)menuRightItem2Touch:(id)sender {
    _menuRightItem2.selected = !_menuRightItem2.selected;
}
```

Comment: What is `_menuRightItem2` ?

Comment: try change  `continuous` property of slider to `NO` . Then i think u dont need to check the _menuRightItem2.selected

Comment: _menuRightItem 2 is a UIbutton

Comment: Note that you **always** (except in `init...` methods or in the `getter` and `setter` methods itself) use accessors for your ivars! So you should never use `_menuRightItem2.selected` but `self.menuRightItem2.selected`

Answer (score 1):

`[_menuRightItem2 isSelected]` returns a bool

you can directly use this method in the `if` statement, which is the recommended way to do it, rather than equating it to `YES`

so try and use

```
if([_menuRightItem2 isSelected]){

}
```

hope it helps.

Comment: Can you please add detail to your answer? Why should he do this? Just saying "try and use" is not a good answer.

Comment: @Popeye .. now this is something useful your doing.

Answer (score 0):

Well , I tried to implement your code on basis of this understanding:
`_menuRightItem2` is `UIButton` and is listening for `UIControlEventTouchUpInside` events using

```
-(IBAction)menuRightItem2Touch:(id)sender method.
```

There are two sliders (IBOutlets) `slider 1` , `slider2`. Both listen  for `ValueChanged` Events using

```
-(IBAction) sliderValueChanged:(UISlider*)sender
```

The code seems to run perfectly. Please make sure you have made `_menuRightItem2` listen to -

```
-(IBAction)menuRightItem2Touch:(id)sender
```

Comment: Well the code should only work when menuRightItem2 is selected, thats what im trying to accomplish here.

Comment: Yes the code only worked when I selected the button and moved the sliders. Try Debugging and make sure the control goes to - (IBAction)menuRightItem2Touch:(id)sender when you select the button.

Comment: Could you maybe upload the project you made? See if I can spot the issue.

Comment: What does the debugging say? Does control go to (IBAction)menuRightItem2Touch:(id)sender method?

Answer (score 0):

check whether the button is selected, if not use the setselected function as shown below

```
- (IBAction)menuRightItem2Touch:(id)sender {    
    if([_menuRightItem2 isSelected])
    {        
        [_menuRightItem2 setSelected:NO];        
    }    
    else{
        [_menuRightItem2 setSelected:YES];
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please add detail to your answer? Why should he do this? Just saying "try with" is not a good answer.